# This program return nothing

Tags: c++, function, stdstring

I am trying to write the following code so that it might return `Hello, World!`.

```
using std::string;
using namespace std;
std::string hello()
{
    return "Hello, World!";
}
int main()
{
    hello();
    return 0;
}
```

having the code compiler run with 0 errors, nor Waring, and run, then a bank result as shown in the attached pic.
Thus can anybody figure out what's missing such that it returns the desired result!

[running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUnTT.jpg)

Comment: Are you trying to print the string? Try `std::cout << "Hello, World!;"`

Comment: About [using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)...

Comment: To go with the beginners book recommendation, that should teach you that system header like `iostream` and `string` should be included using angle-brackets `<>`, as in `#include <iostream>`.

Comment: @Blaze in their case `cout << hello()`

Comment: actually  i want to use similar function in the future so that i would not be having to write the message every time

Comment: ??? When should which function would print what  "every time". I believe I am not the only one who can't understand what you want to tell us!

Comment: You should format your code properly so it is readable. Look how the samples in your beginner's C text book are formatted. Also don't post pictures of text but post text as text.

Comment: You might be confusing the two common senses of "output": it can mean both "something that a program prints" and "something that a function returns to its caller".

Answer (score 4):

Your function `hello()` returns the string, "Hello, world!" but, after you've called that function from `main`, you don't do anything with the returned value.

You need to output something! Try this minor modification:

```
int main ()
{
    std::cout << hello() << std::endl; // So you can avoid "using namespace std!"
    return 0;
}
```